# Incompatible object types

Tags: flowtype

```
/* @flow */

type optionsType = Array<{id: string | number, name: string}>;
type modelsType = Array<{id: number, name: string}>;

function getOptions(options: optionsType): string {
  return options.reduce((a, e) => {
    return a + `<option value="${e.id.toString()}">${e.name}</option>`;
  }, '');
}

const options: modelsType = [
  {id: 1, name: 'punto'},
  {id: 2, name: 'duo'},
  {id: 500, name: 'cinquecento'},
];
console.log(getOptions(options));
```

The above example complains `Cannot call "getOptions" with "options" bound to "options" because number [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property "id" of array element.` but in my understanding the `modelsType` is just more generic than the `optionsType`. Why does flow complain and how can I get this to work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
let second: secondType = first;
```

were allowed as-is, it would mean that it's valid to do

```
second.id = "some-id";
```

but that would corrupt the type of `firstType` since it's the same object, and the type is `number`, but it's now been assigned a string.

To make this work, you need to say that `secondType.id` is read-only, or "covariant". You can do this by changing

```
type secondType = {id: string | number, name: string};
```

to

```
type secondType = {+id: string | number, name: string};
```

([Example on flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZhQCWATgM4YAquBAvGAN5EAmAXGAHYCuAtgEZ4SAGk4BDHnnYUSRDgHMAvgG5MNMGTwBjOB2bV8YegwDULKRhnywAH068BwsRPOXFK1No4VCpCu2LkVGpGZmAAjCIc4pJgAORhscqoMHgY6lo6bOmeesE+gUpAA))

Comment: Thank you! In my use case, I have a function that takes an array of objects with the type {id: string|number, name: string} as it can process id's of type string and number. This function is now sometimes invoked with an array of type {id: string, name: string} and other times with an array of type {id: number, name: string}. When now trying to to specify the secondType as a covariant I get the following error: property `id` is read-only in `secondType` [1] but writable in object type [2] in array element.
 - number [3] is incompatible with string [4] in property `id` of array element

Comment: You may need to make the function argument type `$ReadOnlyArray` instead of `Array` for the same reason. If that doesn't help, please update the question with examples.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution to my use case:

```
/* @flow */

type optionsType = $ReadOnlyArray<{+id: string | number, name: string}>;
type modelsType = Array<{id: number, name: string}>;

function getOptions(options: optionsType): string {
  return options.reduce((a, e) => {
    return a + `<option value="${e.id.toString()}">${e.name}</option>`;
  }, '');
}

const options: modelsType = [
  {id: 1, name: 'punto'},
  {id: 2, name: 'duo'},
  {id: 500, name: 'cinquecento'},
];
console.log(getOptions(options));
```